# C newbie: can I have fixed-size dynamically allocated structs?

Tags: c, struct

To be more specific, I would like to have something like this:

```
struct Image {
    unsigned width;
    unsigned height;
    char data[width*height*4];
}
```

where the size of `data` is static, for each instance of `Image`.

EDIT: I have seen similar SE questions, but they all force me to allocate "by hand" the right amount of memory. Is there no way to force the size of `data` to be `width*height*4`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible. You'll have to allocate the memory on the heap using malloc.

Comment: Why oh why could I not just use Python for this project